# What is the best way to Charge my MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

What is the best way to Charge my MacBook Retina display laptop.

When (at what battery level), how often, how long?

give me some suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by charge?

Answer (score 2):

Don't let it discharge completely.

Store it for long periods (more than a few days) with the power disconnected and battery at around 50% of capacity.

Don't leave it plugged in and charging for long periods of time.

Apple used to be very explicit with their advice for this question. However that page doesn't seem to exist any more.

Here's my answer to a previous similar question:

Straight from the source:

> For proper maintenance of a lithium-based battery, it’s important to
>   keep the electrons in it moving occasionally. Apple does not recommend
>   leaving your portable plugged in all the time. An ideal use would be a
>   commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the
>   office to charge.

http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html

And for more information this is a useful page: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1446

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an OEM Apple charger. If the one that was originally included with the computer has failed or lost, you should purchase a replacement at an Apple Store or online: http://store.apple.com/us/mac/mac-accessories/power. Just be sure to purchase an identical power supply to what was originally in the box.

Comment: Actually what i mean is how to charge properly. Like what the best way to charge. 
is it ok if i put the lap on charging mode when ever i use the laptop.. or what do u recommend

Comment: My recommendation: don't worry about it. Apple's computers are quite sophisticated when it comes to the batteries and it will largely manage everything. If you are not going to use it for a month, then charge it completely and every now and then drain it then charge it fully, but otherwise don't worry about it.